# A kind of 1984 remake, in an Internet based society

Tags: story-identification, novel, dystopia, society

I am looking for the title and author of a specific novel, a social dystopia that sort of takes after 1984, but takes place on the Internet where some Big Brother, controlled by corporations, watches and filters communications between people. Non conformant people get banned from all social life (social life includes education, culture, business and commercial exchanges, and is all Internet based) and must live in some kind of underground. I am not sure whether it belongs to cyberpunk scifi, but it was sort of close to it. It is possible that the original publication language was not English.

I also wonder whether a movie was derived from it.

Comment: This seems wildly generic and could easily fit any one of a dozen stories; http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/BigBrotherIsWatching

Comment: There is actually a short story - The Machine Stops - that was written before 1984 that matches your description. Except that, in that story the "rebels" live on the surface and the rest of "normal" humanity live underground.

Comment: Hey babou! Any input on the short story @slebetman suggested? Is this the one or does the search continue? :)

Comment: @Jenayah I do not know it.

Comment: Could it be "Little Brother" by Cory Doctorow? I can't be sure as I haven't read it.

Comment: @lolrus No, it is not ... but I guess that when I ask the question, I did not realize there were so many dystopian books. Thanks for replying.

Comment: What is sci-fi or fantasy about it?

Answer (score 2):

John C. Wright's **[Golden Oecumene](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Golden_Oecumene)** trilogy has a portion in which the hero, Phaeton, is shunned by almost everyone, leading to his isolation, and inability to buy anything, including permission to see many of the events going on in his society.

This [review](http://www.emcit.com/emcit100.shtml#Return) mentions:

> For example, early on in the book Wright’s hero, Phaethon, describes
> the cabal of fabulously wealthy magnates who control most of the
> world’s industry as "monopolists".

---

> Phaethon has now been declared outcast by his society and is thus
> unable to use most of the technological gadgetry on which his fellow
> citizens rely. Shorn of its level of VR imagery, his world is shabby
> indeed, full of dull mannequins and lifeless, unadorned surfaces. When
> computers can create anything that the user wants, who cares about
> reality any more?

---

> Phaethon’s luck continues to run true because although every citizen
> in the world has been banned from helping him in any way, at pain of
> joining him in exile, there is one person who is willing to take the
> risk and try to save him.